# Postgres NOT IN performance

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance

I'm currently doing some exploratory work with Postgres 12, and have bumped into an issue I want to try and understand more about. My background is primarily Microsoft SQL Server, so I'm looking at where various differences lie between the two.

Now in SQL Server, the query optimizer is quite good and seeing similar patterns and generating equivalent plans for a given query. However in Postgres, I'm getting different plans: now this isn't the issue - that's fine, and have no issue with, however one of the execution plans turns out incurs a large performance hit, so I don't know if I've missed something obvious, or whether this is just the nature of Postgres (if so, fine, it's something we can work with).

The questions I've trying answer are:

1. Is this behaviour expected?
2. Is `NOT IN` generally best avoided with Postgres where data sizes can't be guranteed?
3. Have I missed something obvious with Postgres that would resolve the problem with the query?

I've created a basic table that I've loaded with various word lists (the scrabble TWL, SOWPODS, and a few others sourced from [this repository on github](https://github.com/lorenbrichter/Words/tree/master/Words)):

```
CREATE TABLE wordlist
(
    src character varying(7) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    word character varying(100) COLLATE public.utf8_uk_ci_ai NOT NULL,
    wordlength integer GENERATED ALWAYS AS (char_length((word)::text)) STORED,
    seqid integer NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (INCREMENT 1 START 1)
)
```

I've got the following indexes on the table:

```
CREATE INDEX ix_words ON wordlist (word);
CREATE INDEX ix_words2 ON wordlist (word) INCLUDE (src);
CREATE INDEX ix_words3 ON wordlist (src) INCLUDE (word);
CREATE INDEX ix_srcword ON wordlist (src, word);
CREATE INDEX ix_wordsrc ON wordlist (word, src);
```

This is more due to experiementation/poking, rather than any actual plan, so apologies if they don't make immediate sense. I appreciate ix_words, ix_words2 and ix_words3 are likely superflouous to requirements given the two indexes.

The collation `utf8_uk_ci_ai` is defined as:

```
CREATE COLLATION public.utf8_uk_ci_ai
    (LC_COLLATE = 'en_GB@colStrength=primary', LC_CTYPE = 'en_GB@colStrength=primary');
```

The breakdown of word counts (`SELECT src, COUNT(*) FROM wordlist GROUP BY src`) in the table looks like this:

[image: Word counts by source]

The three queries I've been comparing are these - they're all intended to do return the same dataset, just in different ways; the first two run quickly (EXCEPT and NOT EXISTS), it's the third one (NOT IN) that has problems:

```
select word from wordlist where src = 'SOWPODS'
except
select word from wordlist where src = 'TWL'

select a.word 
    from wordlist a 
    where a.src = 'SOWPODS' 
        and not exists (select 1 from wordlist b where b.src = 'TWL' and a.word = b.word)

select a.word 
    from wordlist a 
    where a.src = 'SOWPODS' 
        and a.word not in (select word from wordlist b where b.src = 'TWL')
```

The first two complete in a second or so; the third however doesn't complete for minutes. I've killed the query as I don't know how long it would have taken.

The EXPLAIN for the third reads as follows:

```
Gather  (cost=13054.03..1667897336.79 rows=136620 width=13)
  Workers Planned: 2
  ->  Parallel Bitmap Heap Scan on wordlist a  (cost=12054.03..1667882674.79 rows=56925 width=13)
        Recheck Cond: ((src)::text = 'SOWPODS'::text)
        Filter: (NOT (SubPlan 1))
        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on ix_words3  (cost=0.00..7261.72 rows=273239 width=0)
              Index Cond: ((src)::text = 'SOWPODS'::text)
        SubPlan 1
          ->  Materialize  (cost=4758.15..33614.09 rows=177254 width=13)
                ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on wordlist b  (cost=4758.15..31861.82 rows=177254 width=13)
                      Recheck Cond: ((src)::text = 'TWL'::text)
                      ->  Bitmap Index Scan on ix_words3  (cost=0.00..4713.84 rows=177254 width=0)
                            Index Cond: ((src)::text = 'TWL'::text)
```

Graphically, looks like this:

[image]

However if I do the same query with a smaller list in the `NOT IN` (src = 'ME' that has 1000 rows, rather than the 178,000 of src = 'TWL'), I get a much faster result and a different (and simpler) plan:

```
select a.word 
    from good.wordlist a 
    where a.src = 'SOWPODS' 
        and a.word not in (select word from good.wordlist b where b.src = 'ME')
```

EXPLAIN gives:

```
Bitmap Heap Scan on wordlist a  (cost=7304.08..36290.67 rows=136620 width=13)
  Recheck Cond: ((src)::text = 'SOWPODS'::text)
  Filter: (NOT (hashed SubPlan 1))
  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on ix_words3  (cost=0.00..7261.72 rows=273239 width=0)
        Index Cond: ((src)::text = 'SOWPODS'::text)
  SubPlan 1
    ->  Index Only Scan using ix_words3 on wordlist b  (cost=0.43..8.20 rows=1 width=13)
          Index Cond: (src = 'ME'::text)
```

which graphically looks like:

[image]

So it's gone straight to one of the indexes with a smaller list, which it's ignoring for the larger list. Now in MSSQL, all three of these queries give the same execution plan, as a result it's given us more flexibility in how we write SQL as we can trust (to a point) that the query optimizer will do the right thing.

With Postgres, it feels like the approach we need to take to writing SQL needs to be different, hence the three questions I posed at the start of this:

1. Is this behaviour expected?
2. Is `NOT IN` generally best avoided with Postgres where data sizes can't be guranteed?
3. Have I missed something obvious with Postgres that would resolve the problem with the query?

Apologies for the length of this question, felt a truncated version of it wasn't working (I did try).

Comment: In general NOT IN should be avoided because of the surprising behaviour with NULL values. And in Postgres NOT EXISTS is typically the faster alternative anyway, and it's use is indeed [discouraged](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don't_Do_This#Don.27t_use_NOT_IN)

Comment: Ah, useful - that hadn't turned up on searches, thanks!